# How long to beat Disgaea?

Tags: disgaea

I'm wondering if I've got the right strategy at all. There seems to be an awful lot of (admittedly fun) grinding and no visible end in sight to get to complete the story. How long, rough average, in hours, does it take to beat Disgaea?

Are the figures shown [here](http://howlongtobeat.com/gamebreakdown.php?gamename=Disgaea:%20Hour%20of%20Darkness) believable? I'm doubtful for story mode...

Comment: I clocked well over 300 hours on Disgaea.

Comment: @KatieK: Did that get you to the end or are you taking your time?

Comment: I'm way way way into the endgame.  As I recall, I took my time and finished the main story in around 80 hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends entirely on your playing style.  From personal experience, a well planned and experienced play through (with abusing item world and invincible squares to power level at certain points) may take me ~10-15 hours, but since this game is all about grinding, there is really no reason to complete the story that fast.

Comment: I've got to find out how that's even possible (I believe you. My experience just doesn't seem to go that way...). Invincible squares don't come all the time... Also, as I've read elsewhere on gaming, dragons. Lots of dragons.