# What is a good estimate of total play time for Zelda Skyward Sword?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

I want to complete Skyward Sword before Christmas, I'm trying to get a good grasp on how much time I need to finish it off. At the very least, I want to beat the game, but I tend to get most of the items as well (I never quite can get everything, but...) This is the first time that I've played my way through it.

So, what would be a fair estimate of how much total time I need to complete the game?

Comment: It took me ~28 hours from start to finish getting just about everything in the game (beating it the first time).  I'd say I'm above average in this game with no deaths and very few pauses in between.  I'd say a good portion of that was flying back and forth doing various things between the different islands and the surface.  If ignoring getting all of the goddess chests as soon as they are available, I'd say it could be possible for a decent player to do it in 25 hours.

Comment: Why has this question received closed votes? [We](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/23637/how-much-play-time-to-complete-legend-of-zelda-twilight-princess/23647#23647) [have](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35550/how-long-is-the-main-quest) [multiple](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/19220/how-long-to-beat-disgaea) [questions](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/14022/how-long-is-final-fantasy-vii) on the site asking the same type of question, and they have not been closed. If you have a problem with these kinds of question, you need to open a meta.

Comment: @Jeff What the... ?!? You beat it 100% in 28 hours, and you didn't die once?!? Dude, are you like, not human? I'm solely just playing through the game without doing any sidequest stuff, and I'm already almost 14 hours in and I'm just starting the Earth Temple. And I died like, at least 10 times just trying kill my first Skulltula. I never played Twilight Princess on the Wii, so the Wii gaming experience is new for me, and it's HARD. It's easily one of the hardest Zelda games I've ever played. Right now, I'm stuck on how to kill Lizalfos without an Iron Shield... :/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[I've](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/41213/what-is-a-good-estimate-of-total-play-time-for-zelda-skyward-sword) [checked](http://howlongtobeat.com/gamebreakdown.php?gamename=The%20Legend%20of%20Zelda:%20Skyward%20Sword) [out](http://kotaku.com/5861425/shigeru-miyamoto-was-right-zelda-is-50+100-hours-long) [a few](http://www.zeldadungeon.net/2011/11/how-long-is-skyward-sword/) [sources](http://www.gonintendo.com/?mode=viewstory&id=166844), and the average playtime is around 40 hours, although this depends largely on how many side quests you do. People who mostly focused on the main quest had times closer to 35, where as those that spent more time on side quests were closer to 45 or higher.

> It should be noted that after you beat the game, you unlock [Hero Mode](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/37798/in-what-way-is-the-game-different-or-the-same-when-you-play-in-hero-mode). This is essentially a second quest with increased difficulty.

Comment: Hmm, I must have been very efficient at what I was doing.  ^_^

Comment: The spoiler is pretty standard for Zelda games, dating all the way back to the original.

Comment: @Powerlord It was in some games, but not all. Just putting it in spoiler tags in case some users would prefer to be surprised.

Answer (score 2):

I completely finished it in 37 hrs, and i die more than most people that i know, so i would say that is a fair estimate.

Answer (score 2):

For me, I took 45 hours to beat the game, I did lots of side quests!

Answer (score 1):

I finished the game in about 65 hours.  This includes all side quests and goddess cubes.  I never beat the high scores in the bug hunt challenge or the cut bamboo challenge.

Answer (score 1):

It took me over 100 hours to beat hero mode and the main quest.

Answer (score 1):

45 hrs normal and hero mode, all goddess cubes, beat the hero mode thunder dragon battle (all 12), all side quests and finished the game with all the gorko wall drawings, hint fo the hero mode dragon battles, begin with the hoard battle, it take a lot of time to complete

Answer (score 1):

I'm at 32 hours in the last dungeon but it is possible to beat the game much faster.

speedruns (current best: 5:34 hours):
http://zeldaspeedruns.com/leaderboards/ss/any

100% speedruns (current best: 8:53 hours):
http://zeldaspeedruns.com/leaderboards/ss/100

Answer (score -6):

Six hours straight, without dying or resting.

Comment: Do you have any links or evidence to back up this statement?

Comment: I'd love to see this speed run